# What's a good tool to help students perform peer review as a graded assignment?

Tags: peer-review, teaching, writing

I am teaching an academic writing course for grad students and part of the course content involves peer review activities on one another's writings. These peer reviews will receive a letter grade.

Do you know of any tools/templates/techniques to facilitate this both from the students perspective (e.g. a form or even a Perusall-like tool) and the instructor's perspective (grading peer reviews will be very time consuming unless there's some standardization).

Tips or creative ideas are welcome!

Comment: Which particular problem do you try to solve with a tool? Students need clear guidance about what they should comment on in their reviews, that is, criteria or dimensions of assessment. Once you have those criteria clear, you can build a template in which each criterion becomes a section.

Answer (score 2):

For peer-review purposes, I've been content with the [Workshop activity in Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Workshop_activity).

You can set up peer review template forms, change the "blindness" (anonymity) of the process, modify the number of peer reviews per submission, and you have a single platform which allows the grading of both the paper submission and the peer review reports.

Answer (score 1):

We had very good experiences using Calibrated Peer Review (CPR) http://cpr.molsci.ucla.edu/Home for "writing across the curriculum" for undergraduates.  I think it should fit your purposes as well.

Some discussion https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1062843.pdf

Answer (score -1):

If you want the students to learn to peer review like a professional scientist, they need to understand that article peer reviewing does not come with a template.  Each paper is different and each peer review should be adjusted to match.  That said, here's a
[checklist that students could use.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/148045/13240)

[Here is a similar resource for mathematics.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/131593/13240)

If you want students to learn to peer review grant applications, your funding agency probably does provide a template.

Comment: "peer reviewing does not come with a template" That it not universally correct. I've reviewed for journals that had a pretty rigid template. As a reviewer I hated it and I'm sure the authors found the review also less useful than a free-form review. Even journals without such a template often have some kind of point system that the reviewer needs to fill in.